# Кодировки и словари в python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

Есть функция

```
def saveJSON(data, path):
    dataW = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    file = open(path, mode='w', encoding = "UTF-8")
    file.write(dataW)
    file.close()>
```

Функция получает словарь и записывает его в файл,  проблема в том, что если пишу на кириллице, то значение по ключу получается [image: кодировка] и так далее, очевидно не та кодировка, но в начале программы прописано`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` и `encoding = "UTF-8"` при открытии файла прописан, как же исправить [image: кодировка]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это как раз та кодировка. JSON по стандарту может содержать только ascii-символы, соответственно, все прочие будут преобразованы в escape-последовательности utf-8. Если вам нужны строки в первозданном виде, то к вызову `dumps` надо добавить параметр `ensure_ascii=False`.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало, означает ли это, что encoding = "UTF-8" можно убрать?

Comment: @Cowboyserg нет, как раз с `ensure_ascii=True` вы могли бы убрать параметр `encoding="UTF-8"`.